# livewire form not going through laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I've been watching a comment livewire tutorial from codecoure. Everything worked fine till a form that will store the comment is not going through. I tried dd, but I get nothing. In the url after the slug it says comment=whateverItyped. i've been using this tutorial in a story posting board, but I'm clueless where the error is. I've even copied and pasted the exact same form and method but nothing goes through the form.

The form:

```html
<div class="min-w-0 flex-1">
    <form wire:submit.prevent="postComment">
        <div>
            <label for="comment" class="sr-only">Comment body</label>
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="3"
                class="shadow-sm block w-full focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 border-gray-300 rounded-md @error('newCommentState.body') border-red-500 @enderror"
                placeholder="Write something"
                wire:model.defer="newCommentState.body">
            </textarea>
            @error('newCommentState.body')
                <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-500">{{ $message }}</p>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3 flex items-center justify-between">
            <button type="submit" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500">
                Comment
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Since I'm clueless where this error is. I don't know what more I should post than the form. There is anohter method that gets the comments, and that works fine. I think it is something with the post request but I'm unsure since I'm new to livewire

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Comments extends Component
{
    public $model;

    public function postComment()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'newCommentState.body' => 'required'
        ]);

        $comment = $this->model->comments()->make($this->newCommentState);
        $comment->user()->associate(auth()->user());

        $comment->save();

        $this->newCommentState = [
            'body' => ''
        ];

        $this->goToPage(1);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $comments = $this->model
        ->comments()
        ->with('user', 'children.user', 'children.children')
        ->parent()
        ->latest()
        ->get();

        return view('livewire.comments', [
            'comments' => $comments
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to Livewire too but I can't see `newCommentState` object in your Livewire Comments class and how `wire:model.defer="newCommentState.body` in your blade template should access it.

Comment: But I may not know the technique used In that tutorial.

Comment: @Dave it's not that which is the issue. I hadn't come to that part yet. I just copied the exact code from the tutorial and it's the same issue

Comment: If you add `dd('postComment');` before your validation inside `postComment()` function and press your `submit` button, do you see the `dd` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using `$newCommentState`, but never declares it.

Add a new attribute `public $newCommentState;`.

I would also create a method like that:

```php
// this will initialize $newCommentState
public function mount() {
    $this->newCommentState = [
        'body' => ''
    ];

}
```